# Replace part of IP in batch script

Tags: batch-file, ip-address, subnet

I know there is a similar topic however it doesn't work for me. My problem is that want to be able change my ip address automatically

So for an example I have subnet /29 with 5 working ips with first usable ip let say will be 12.345.678.90 I would like script to change this ip for 12.345.678.91 and for 12.345.678.92 so difference between the original is +1 and +2 and than script would have to point these IP's on different location on the script or txt file. my problem is that I have no idea how to make script change those IP for +1 and +2. Note that IP that I will paste will be different each time. Hope that I clearly explain what I need.

so far i get somethink like that:

```
set /p WAN1=">>"
set /p WAN2=">>"
set /p WAN3=">>"
set /p WAN4=">>"

set /a WAN5=%WAN4%+1
set /a WAN6=%WAN4%+2
```

however i would prefer to paste whole IP address instead of typing each module.

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: A sample input file and expected output will help to get more answers.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. You should choose **one** tag, bash and batch-file normally exclude each other.

Comment: Do you mean "bash" or "batch"? It can't be both.

Comment: If this is bash and not `batch` then you could use `awk`: `echo "192.168.1.1" | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="."}{print $1,$2,$3,$4+1}'`

Comment: I meant batch sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 0):

split the IP, add one to the last number and reassemble:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p "wlan4=WLAN4: "
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%wlan4%") do (
  set /a last=%%d+1
  echo %%a.%%b.%%c.!last!
)
```

or if you prefer not using delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set /p "wlan4=WLAN4: "
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%wlan4%") do (
  set /a last=%%d
  set "base=%%a.%%b.%%c"
)
set /a w5=last+1
set /a w6=last+2
set "wlan5=%base%.%w5%"
set "wlan6=%base%.%w6%"
set wlan
```

Comment: Hi Thank you a lot this is working perfectly, thank you very much this was bothering me for last few days